# What is optimal way to connect accounts to 2FA on phone?

Tags: password-management, password-policy, multi-factor, account-security

I have **Google Acc 0** (GAO) mostly for bank porpoises and some "official" services. This email basically "surname.name@google.com" and I put in my old C.V. and some other contact information.
When I got Android phone I decided to crate **Google Acc 1** (GAN)
I redirected mail from some other mailboxes that I was still using, to it, and put GAO as recovery account for GAN, I am using GAN at the moment as my official contact mail. Also added GAO to mail in my phone. Protected both with 2FA - google code generator on my phone and set my phone number as recovery number.
Also I am using LastPass, which is also dependent on 2FA on phone and its phone number, LastPass account is mail of GAN and its also stores password to that mail so I can easily access to it from PC because I usually using other (not GAO) account on PC and need to use this one rarely.

At this point I understood that something is wrong. My mind get tangled and I decided to draw relationships diagram (below) where arrows mostly represents dependencies (except gathering mail) i.e.

[image]

Comment: Am I correct that you're afraid to lose everything because of 2FA dependent on one device that may be lost?

Comment: @SPRBRN yes but also, I think in over all connection between elements is redundant. I do not know if I am right or wrong so asking for advice.

Answer (score 0):

Questions you should ask:

- What happens if I lose my phone?
- Can I login to Lastpass if I do so?
- Can I login or recover my old and new Gmail?

Key here is your 2FA code generator. What happens if that gets lost? How do you recover from that? Redundancy is a good thing!

Oh and is your phone encrypted? Your SD card as well?